# How to close only one pop-up in a specific portal?

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, popup, addeventlistener, portal

I am writing a small UiKit for **pop-ups** and i've run up into a problem. My code structure is looking somewhere like this:

```
<MainPopup>
  <Popover />
<MainPopup />
```

And pop-ups structure can be presented like this:

```
<KeyboardListener>
  <Portal>
    // some logic here...
  <Portal />
<KeyboardListener/>
```

`<Portal />` component opens pop-up in the `React.createPortal(...)` and `<KeyboardListener />` component looks like this (it basically adds event listener to track when user presses `Escape` button):

```
import { FC, useEffect } from "react"

interface KeyboardListenerProps {
    onClose: () => void
    children: React.ReactNode
}

const KeyboardListener: FC<KeyboardListenerProps> = ({onClose, children}) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        const closeOnEscapeKey = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
            e.stopImmediatePropagation()
            if (e.key === 'Escape') onClose()
        }

        document.body.addEventListener('keydown', closeOnEscapeKey)

        return () => document.body.removeEventListener('keydown', closeOnEscapeKey)
    }, [onClose])

    return (
        <>
            {children}
        </>
    )
}

export default KeyboardListener
```

[image: Main pop-up]

[image: Pop-over in the main pop-up]

But there is a problem! When I am opening pop-over and want to close it by pressing `Escape` the main pop-up is **also getting closed**.

***Question:*** Is there a way to close a specific (last-opened) portal with pop-up with an `Escape` key?

Forgot to mention - every new **portal** is appended to the document after the previous one, here is the code:

```
import { FC, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

interface PortalProps {
    children: React.ReactNode
}

const Portal: FC<PortalProps> = ({ children }) => {
    const [container] = useState(() => document.createElement('div'))

    useEffect(() => {
        
        document.body.appendChild(container)

        return () => {
            document.body.removeChild(container)
        }
    }, [container])

    return ReactDOM.createPortal(children, container)
}

export default Portal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue in kind of imperative way. I've added `<div id="portals" />` to **index.html** file and now I am putting all my portals here. Also, now, when a new `<Portal />` is created it must have a unique id, portal component looks like this:

```
import { FC, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import KeyboardListener from '../../KeyboardListener/KeyboardListener'

interface PortalProps {
    children: React.ReactNode
    onClose: () => void
    id: string
}

const Portal: FC<PortalProps> = ({ children, onClose, id }) => {
    const [container] = useState(() => document.createElement('div'))
    container.id = id

    const portals = document.getElementById('portals')!

    useEffect(() => {
        portals.appendChild(container)

        return () => {
            portals.removeChild(container)
        }
    }, [container, id, onClose, portals])

    return ReactDOM.createPortal(
        <KeyboardListener id={id} onClose={onClose} portals={portals}>
            {children}
        </KeyboardListener>, container)
}

export default Portal
```

Then I've created `<KeyboardListener />` component which is listening **Escape** button press. Every new pop-up `onClose()` is closured in different `<Portal />`, so I am taking the last element from  every time button is clicked and calling specific `onClose` for portal with **appropriate** id:

```
import React, { FC, useEffect } from 'react'

interface KeyboardListenerProps {
    portals: HTMLElement
    onClose: () => void
    id: string
    children: React.ReactNode
}

const KeyboardListener: FC<KeyboardListenerProps> = ({
    portals,
    onClose,
    id,
    children
}) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const closeOnEscapeKey = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
            if (e.key === 'Escape') {
                const portals = document.getElementById('portals')!
                if (
                    portals.children &&
                    portals.children[portals.children.length - 1]?.id === id
                ) {
                    onClose()
                }
            }
        }
        document.body.addEventListener('keydown', closeOnEscapeKey)

        return () => document.body.removeEventListener('keydown', closeOnEscapeKey)
    }, [id, portals, onClose])

    return <>{children}</>
}

export default KeyboardListener
```

***Bonus:***

I also know more elegant way to solve this issue, but I haven't realized it yet. You need a store in which you will put `onClose()` every time a new `<Portal />` is created. Then every time **Escape** button is pressed you will call the last `onClose()` in this store.

Answer (score 1):

let every popup have some id, everytime you open popup add this id to some array, let onClose take last id from array and unmount only this popup